# Can i change the App availability multiple times?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Can i change the App availability date multiple times?. i.e Making it available for sale and changing it to future, again making it available etc.

Example:
I make an available today, its get on to the sale, people download it and use it.
I realize that there is a use case missed, but to confirm that i need more time, i immediately change the App's available date in Future, may be like 10 days and then test the use case and again make the app available.

If this can be done, i.e making it available and moving it to future, again making it available... Is there a restriction on number of times that you can do it, is there any Apple policy around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a limit on how many times you can change an app's availability date. Note that there's a 24–48 hour delay for your change to the availability date to be reflected across every App Store.

Comment: Let me rephrase if i understand it correctly, when you make the availability date which was in future and make it available to the current day, it would take another 24-48 hours to start appearing on the App Stores..?

Comment: @user3515578 Worldwide and in search, yes. The direct link should go to the app within a few hours, but the point is there's a delay and you can't *guarantee* availability for at least 24 hours.